# Which is better for doing calcculations? Switch case, if-statment?

Tags: c#, math, if-statement, switch-statement

I have an assignment that requires a lot conversions between different units of measure. I have all of the work done except the math part. My question is, and if anyone has a better solution im all ears, would it be best to do these calculations using a  switch or an if statement? Here is a little background info about my program. I have a text file that contains 9 different units of measurement along with their lengths in terms of feet separated by a comma that looks like as follows:

inch,.083333
fathom,6
foot,1
furlong,660
kilometer,3281.5
meter,3.2815
mile,5280
rod,16.5
yard,3

So, i have successfully dumped all of the information into a string array. From there i split the string array twice. The first time i split the string array, i created a new string array that would hold only the names for each unit of measure. The second time i split the string array, i did it so i could create a double array to hold all of the numeric values for each unit of measurement. Now i need to do the math portion. My program is going to display the nine different units of measure, request the unit to convert from, requests the unit to convert to, request the quantity (or total measurement) to convert, and then display the converted quantity. SO far this is what i have:

```
private void SandC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = false;
    splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;

    string[] lengths = File.ReadAllLines("Units.txt");
    int count=0;
    string[] unitName=new string[count];
    while (!(count==10))
    {
        count++;

        lbLengths.Items.Add(count+"."+" "+lengths[count-1].Split(new Char[]{','})[0]);

    }
}
private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string orginalunits = tborginalUnits.Text;
    int orginalunits1;
    string desiredunits = tbDesiredunits.Text;
    int desiredunits1;
    string lenghttoConvert = tbConvert.Text;
    double lenghttoConvert1;
    string[] lengths = File.ReadAllLines("Units.txt");
    int count = lengths.Length;
    double[] units = new double[lengths.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length;i++)
    {


        units[i] = Convert.ToDouble(lengths[i].Split(new Char[] { ',' })[1]);

    }
    if ((double.TryParse(lenghttoConvert, out lenghttoConvert1)) && (Int32.TryParse(orginalunits, out orginalunits1)) && (Int32.TryParse(desiredunits, out desiredunits1)))
    {

        if ((desiredunits1==3)&&(orginalunits1==1))
        {
            double answer;
            answer = units[0] * lenghttoConvert1;
            Math.Round(answer, 3);
            mtbOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(answer);
            lblConversion.Text = "Converted to foot length";

        }

    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("In the'Orginal and Desired Units' boxes, please enter only the numbers 1 -9, and in the 'Length to Covert' Box, please enter only numbers"); 

}
```

So as you can see in the button click event, i am at the part where the conversions should take place. My question, once again, is what would be the best method i should use to handle all of these calculations? I already have 1 if statement, and if i am going to do if statements, i feel as if it will be very tedious and was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this. Thanks for your help guys, i really do appreciate it.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Many if's should be replaced with `switch` simply for readability. In both cases the compiler will probably optimize it to be just about the same, and in any case you should only think about performance after you know it takes a hit. First get your code to work and don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to use a little math to avoid conditionals altogether.

No matter what's the original and target units are, you can do the conversion through by converting the original units to feet and then converting feet to the target unit.

Let's say you want to go from `X` units at index `i` to units at index `j`. All you need to do is dividing `X` by `units[i]`, and multiplying by `units[j]`. No conditionals or switches are required.

> How would the program know which unit to choose?

This depends on the organization of your program. This could be a very simple task if you use drop-down boxes for unit names in your UI, because the index of the selected item will be the same as the index of the conversion rate in the `units[]` array.

Comment: so what your saying is that if i want to go from inches "units[0]" to feet "units[2]", i need to divide the "lenghttoConvert1" by "units[0], then multiply that by units[2]? If so, then how would that be coded? I cannot see this being done without using some type of conditional statement. How would the program know which unit to choose?

Comment: @Spr89 The answer to this depends a great deal on the organization of your user interface. I made one suggestion in the edit, but other approaches are definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given this specific example, if statements and switch statements are both redundant.

Another way to solve this would be to create a mapping table (two dimensional array) where you specify the conversion multiplier between both units especially that your code already uses digits to represent units instead of their actual names.

For example

```
C[1][1] = 1;
C[1][2] = 3.1;
C[1][3] = 5;
C[1][4] = 0.33;
C[2][1] = 1/C[1][2]; 
....
....
C[4][1] = 1/C[1][4];
```

After creating that array, you can simply plugin the numbers depending on the source and destination currencies to do the conversion.

You can further improve on the above by creating one or two if statement that check whether the first parameter for the array is less than the second or not. If yes, then take the value as it is, if not take the reciprocal of the value. Therefore, you dont have to fill the entire array with values such as:

```
C[2][1] = 1/C[1][2];  
C[4][1] = 1/C[1][4];
```

Hope that helped.